# iPad web-app seems to redraw in blocks. Is there an optimization to stop this?

Tags: ipad, transition, web-applications, redraw

For instance I have a simple transition on the home page that fades between three different images. In a browser this fades beautifully, but on the iPad it redraws it with blocks (imagine Google Maps loading very slowly).  Is there something I can do to stop this?  It's quite ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else hase this issue I have found the cause.

The full answer is here: http://www.appleinsider.com/articles/11/03/15/full_screen_web_apps_fail_to_use_nitro_acceleration_in_apples_ios_4_3.html

But in short, it's because as a web app the iPad does not use the nitro accelerator to render the pages while the native browser does.  It seems that there currently is no solution.

**--Update**
Apparently, the blocking is also caused by using hardware acceleration. Removing the translate3d call that enabled hardware acceleration made the movement a little choppy but resolved the rendering bug.  I guess we are just waiting on Apple to work out these glitches.